# Check table and run stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server and here is the scenario.

Below is the workflow:

1. We will get data from upstream for every 10 - 15 secs. Upstream will directly insert data into our tables - this is our `Staging` table
2. We wrote an `after insert` trigger on this staging table which will move data from `Staging` to `Master` table. And now master table also has an `After insert` trigger which will take 23 secs to complete
3. We are not sure when is the final batch of data will be submitted by upstream

Problem area where solution needed

1. As upstream tries to push data into our staging table for every 10 secs and if the trigger on `Staging` start it will wait until trigger on master table is completed. Now during time of execution 24 sec if we get data from upstream as STG is locked data received now is dropped due to locks

If there is any potential work around please let us know

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: We are using SQL Server

Comment: Why use a staging table? The upstream process could just call a stored procedure with a TVP to insert into the master table directly. If that's not an option, post your create table DDL and trigger code.

Comment: If you are inserting data into a staging table that is then loaded into a master table, then why not insert directly into the master table? Or, are you performing any checks on the data within the trigger?

Comment: A trigger on a production table that takes 24 seconds is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: That said, you should probably replace your staging table with a Service Broker queue.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) suggested you could just get rid of staging table and process everything using stored procedure.

Maybe a better, however a trickier, way would be use a message queue instead of a staging table and activation procedure that will deal with rows based on your business logic.

This could be a more suited and less blocking way for streaming data.